# what is the number part in mapping.txt

Tags: android, android-proguard

A generated mapping.txt like following

```
com.abc.media.MediaAudioEncoder$AudioThread -> nq:
com.abc.media.MediaAudioEncoder this$0 -> a
100:100:void <init>(com.abc.media.MediaAudioEncoder) -> <init>
105:158:void run() -> run
100:100:void <init>
```

what does "100:100" "105:158" means ?

Answer (score 2):

These are line numbers which indicate range where method is defined.

So for each class, there is that structure:
1st line, without indentation, shows translation of class name.

```
com.example.myapp.MainActivity -> com.example.myapp.a:
```

Next, lines with indentation, shows translation of that class' fields and methods.

```
    int num -> a   //fields
    java.lang.String str -> b
    15:20:void <init>() -> <init>   //contructor, between 15th and 20th line
    27:54:void onCreate(android.os.Bundle) -> onCreate //not obfuscated method, between 27th and 54th line
    60:88:void foo() -> a   //obfuscated method
    90:93:void bar() -> b
```

Note that not every class/method/field will be obfuscated. Code which depends on reflections (calling methods by their name, as a string) won't work after obfuscation process. That's why sometimes you will want to exclude certain part of code from that process by editing your proguard-rules file.

Comment: range in .class file or in .dex files ?

Comment: In your original .java file, so you can even find original method only by looking at line numbers (in known class)